# how to get value from a index value

Tags: tensorflow

The tensor is `A_tensor`,has shape `[3,3,3]` and I want get the last axis's value by index.

How do I do that in Tensorflow?

```
A_tensor =tf.constant([[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5]])
```

How to get tensor `([[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]])`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tf.gather()`:

```
A_tensor =tf.constant([[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5]])
tf.gather(A_tensor,[[0,1]],axis=-1)
```